# Images of the $3$-dimensional solvable geometry

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

This is more of a mathematical art question. Most people are familiar with the [mathematical movie "Not Knot",](https://youtu.be/zd_HGjH7QZo) which explores a hyperbolic $3$-manifold. My question is: are there any images along the same line of the three-dimensional $Solv$ geometry?

Comment: This question is related, but different http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24572/drawing-of-the-eight-thurston-geometries

Comment: Presumably you are looking for something along the lines of the ideas and intuition described here (by Thurston): https://youtu.be/4jdmkUQDWtQ?t=1452 but with the slickness of "Not Knot"?

Comment: @NeilHoffman Actually, I am just looking for a bunch of images, so certainly the video you linked to is very relevant!